# Abnormal Alexa score: the more popular site has a worse rank

Tags: seo, ecommerce, pagerank, ranking, alexa

I have 2 websites of ecommerce in France and for these websites I have a strange behaviour of the alexa results. Here are some statistics about the websites :

**Unique Visits January 2012**

- Website A : 158,828
- Website B : 58,867

**Number of Search Results google**

- Website A : 5,100
- Website B : 56,000

**Links to my site**

- Website A : 3,120
- Website B : 2,180

**ALEXA Score**

- Website A : 405,804
- Website B : 278,944

How does it come that website B with 1/3 of the visitors of website A have a much better Alexa Score ( x2 ) then website A?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because Alexa does not know how much traffic your website gets. They depend on users with their toolbar visiting website to get an idea of how much traffic to website gets. So the lesser trafficked site is getting more Alexa toolbar visitors then the other site.

That's why you shouldnt be paying any attention to Alexa.